# PHP snippet to Smarty code

Tags: php, smarty

I'm looking to convert some PHP code to smarty code, but am struggling with the function part.

```
<?php function get_client_ip_env() {
          $ipaddress = '';
            if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
              $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
            else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
              $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
            else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
              $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
            else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
              $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
            else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
              $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
            else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
              $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
            else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
           return $ipaddress;}

          $user_ip = get_client_ip_env();
          $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
          $country = $geo["geoplugin_countryCode"];

            if ($country == "GB") {
              echo "You are from Great Britain";
             } else {
              echo "Please visit our other website.";
            }                       ?>
```

The only bit I can do is the last if statement. Any assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe do this logic in the file that is loading the template in question, and then pass its result to smarty as a variable? That feels neater, maybe - keeping your display logic separate.

In answer to your question though, you could for instance use `{php}` tags which allow you to write raw php code that will be untouched when the .tpl files are used to generate the php files that display the page - there's some more information [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Way late, but perhaps useful for others:

```
{capture name="ip_behind_proxy" assign="ip_behind_proxy"}{strip}
    {assign var="ipaddress"             value=""}

    {assign var=HTTP_CLIENT_IP          value='HTTP_CLIENT_IP'|getenv}
    {assign var=HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR    value='HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'|getenv}
    {assign var=HTTP_X_FORWARDED        value='HTTP_X_FORWARDED'|getenv}
    {assign var=HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR      value='HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'|getenv}
    {assign var=HTTP_FORWARDED          value='HTTP_FORWARDED'|getenv}
    {assign var=REMOTE_ADDR             value='REMOTE_ADDR'|getenv}

    {if ! empty($HTTP_CLIENT_IP)}
         {$ipaddress = $HTTP_CLIENT_IP}
    {elseif ! empty($HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)}
         {$ipaddress = $HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}
    {elseif ! empty($HTTP_X_FORWARDED)}
         {$ipaddress = $HTTP_X_FORWARDED}
    {elseif ! empty($HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR)}
         {$ipaddress = $HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR}
    {elseif ! empty($HTTP_FORWARDED)}
         {$ipaddress = $HTTP_FORWARDED}
    {elseif ! empty($REMOTE_ADDR)}
         {$ipaddress = $REMOTE_ADDR}
    {elseif ! empty($smarty.server.REMOTE_ADDR)}
         {$ipaddress = $smarty.server.REMOTE_ADDR}
    {else}
         {$ipaddress = "ONBEKEND"}
    {/if}

    {if $ipaddress}
        {$ipaddress}
    {/if}
{/strip}{/capture}


{if $smarty.capture.ip_behind_proxy ne ""}{$smarty.capture.ip_behind_proxy}{/if}
```